# Execute a php file x amount of times one after another

Tags: linux, php

If I execute a php file like such:

```
 php phpfiletoexecute.php
```

It will run 1 time.

What I would like to do, is run the php file example 5 times one after another (1st completes, 2nd run starts, 3rd, 4th, 5th, end)

What is the command to use?

Comment: `for i in {1..5}; do php phpfiletoexecute.php; done`

Comment: do you care about the success of each run (to determine whether to run another time) - or just run 5 regardless?

Comment: @JeffSchaller no, just that the previous run has completed - so 5 runs one after another regardless

Comment: Then hopefully @TomHunt will write his comment up as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in {1..5}; do php phpfiletoexecute.php; done
```

This is the stupidest possible version; given more information, you could do things like check if each run succeeded, look at their output if any, and so forth.

Comment: So i just pop that in a php script or run that from the command line? Also the script I'm running doesnt output anything, it reaches a limit and ends. This is a work around. Really appreciate the quick response!

Comment: This is run from the command line, or placed in a shell script.

Comment: Excellent, worked like a charm thank you @Tom Hunt will accept once it allows me